# What does "prometheus-operated" service do?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, kubernetes-service, prometheus-operator

Prometheus-operator seems to generate `promethues-operated` service which just points to Prometheus instance at port 9090.

What does this service do? We define other services to point at our Prometheus cluster.

What would be repercussions on removing `prometheus-operated` service?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation, `prometheus-operated` is a governing service for statefulsets, in other words it's Prometheus's service endpoint which is used for its functioning.

Below are some references:

> What you are referring to is the governing service that point to the
> synthesized Prometheus statefulsets. In the case of a second
> Prometheus in the same namespace the same governing service will be
> referenced, which in turn will add the IPs of all pods of the separate
> Prometheus instances to the same governing service.

Taken from [Rename Prometheus Operator Service #3805](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3805)

Also another reference to the same idea:

> The Prometheus Operator reconciles services called prometheus-operated
> and alertmanager-operated, which are used as governing Services for
> the StatefulSets. To perform this reconciliation

Taken from [Prometheus operator/Documentation/readme](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/1b13e573c7ad533010407544f88dc4a78320b134/Documentation/rbac.md)

One more commit that confirms that `prometheus-operated` is a governing service:

> pkg/prometheus: add Thanos service port to governing service
> Currently, for service discovery of Prometheus instances a separate
> headless service must be deployed.
>
> This adds the Thanos grpc port to the existing Prometheus statefulset
> governing service if a Thanos sidecar is given in the Prometheus
> custom resource specification.
>
> This way no additional service has to be deployed.

Taken from [pkg/prometheus: add Thanos service port to governing service #2754](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/pull/2754/commits/86d42de53ca2c2ea0d32264818d9750f409979da)

---

> What would be repercussions on removing prometheus-operated service.

It's quite old answer, but since this is a part of Prometheus and Prometheus components will fail if the service is removed:

> The prometheus-operated service is an implementation detail of the
> Prometheus Operator, it should not be touched, especially as all
> Prometheus instances will be registered in this service

Taken from [kube-prometheus chart creates 3 different services pointing to the same pods #522](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/522#issuecomment-319016693)

---

[Code where this service is created](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/pkg/prometheus/statefulset.go#L267-L313)

Taking into consideration that:

```
const (
    governingServiceName            = "prometheus-operated"
    ...
)
```

Comment: What does governing service mean? We create separate service to expose prometheus.

Comment: Governing service is a kubernetes term used for `statefulsets` - see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id). My assumption based on docs/mentions I found is service used by operator to control prometheus deployment (not literally, in general) as an endpoint. You can see that there are [a few mentions even in code](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aprometheus-operator+prometheus-operated&type=code). I can raise a question in their GitHub repo to have some more details.